# Python 2to3 conversion of imported Google libraries

Tags: python, google-authentication, python-2to3, google-python-api

I have succesfully run the [Python2 Google Example Youtube upload code.](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/upload_video.py) Now, i want to try converting this code to Python3. When i convert it with 2to3 tool, the result is like below. And if i try to run it with Python3 i get an error such below. I use Rasbian OS. Which Python3 libraries am i have to import instead of `google.oauth2.credentials`, `google_auth_oauthlib.flow`, `google_auth_oauthlib.flow`?

#### Converted Python3 code:

```
import argparse
import http.client
import httplib2
import os
import random
import time

import google.oauth2.credentials
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow


# Explicitly tell the underlying HTTP transport library not to retry, since
# we are handling retry logic ourselves.
httplib2.RETRIES = 1

# Maximum number of times to retry before giving up.
MAX_RETRIES = 10

# Always retry when these exceptions are raised.
RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS = (httplib2.HttpLib2Error, IOError, http.client.NotConnected,
  http.client.IncompleteRead, http.client.ImproperConnectionState,
  http.client.CannotSendRequest, http.client.CannotSendHeader,
  http.client.ResponseNotReady, http.client.BadStatusLine)

# Always retry when an apiclient.errors.HttpError with one of these status
# codes is raised.
RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES = [500, 502, 503, 504]

# The CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE variable specifies the name of a file that contains
# the OAuth 2.0 information for this application, including its client_id and
# client_secret. You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from
# the {{ Google Cloud Console }} at
# {{ https://cloud.google.com/console }}.
# Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
# For more information about using OAuth2 to access the YouTube Data API, see:
#   https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication
# For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, see:
#   https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = 'client_secret.json'

# This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
# authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload']
API_SERVICE_NAME = 'youtube'
API_VERSION = 'v3'

VALID_PRIVACY_STATUSES = ('public', 'private', 'unlisted')


# Authorize the request and store authorization credentials.
def get_authenticated_service():
  flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES)
  credentials = flow.run_console()
  return build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials = credentials)

def initialize_upload(youtube, options):
  tags = None
  if options.keywords:
    tags = options.keywords.split(',')

  body=dict(
    snippet=dict(
      title=options.title,
      description=options.description,
      tags=tags,
      categoryId=options.category
    ),
    status=dict(
      privacyStatus=options.privacyStatus
    )
  )

  # Call the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
  insert_request = youtube.videos().insert(
    part=','.join(list(body.keys())),
    body=body,
    # The chunksize parameter specifies the size of each chunk of data, in
    # bytes, that will be uploaded at a time. Set a higher value for
    # reliable connections as fewer chunks lead to faster uploads. Set a lower
    # value for better recovery on less reliable connections.
    #
    # Setting 'chunksize' equal to -1 in the code below means that the entire
    # file will be uploaded in a single HTTP request. (If the upload fails,
    # it will still be retried where it left off.) This is usually a best
    # practice, but if you're using Python older than 2.6 or if you're
    # running on App Engine, you should set the chunksize to something like
    # 1024 * 1024 (1 megabyte).
    media_body=MediaFileUpload(options.file, chunksize=-1, resumable=True)
  )

  resumable_upload(insert_request)

# This method implements an exponential backoff strategy to resume a
# failed upload.
def resumable_upload(request):
  response = None
  error = None
  retry = 0
  while response is None:
    try:
      print('Uploading file...')
      status, response = request.next_chunk()
      if response is not None:
        if 'id' in response:
          print('Video id "%s" was successfully uploaded.' % response['id'])
        else:
          exit('The upload failed with an unexpected response: %s' % response)
    except HttpError as e:
      if e.resp.status in RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES:
        error = 'A retriable HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s' % (e.resp.status,
                                                             e.content)
      else:
        raise
    except RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS as e:
      error = 'A retriable error occurred: %s' % e

    if error is not None:
      print(error)
      retry += 1
      if retry > MAX_RETRIES:
        exit('No longer attempting to retry.')

      max_sleep = 2 ** retry
      sleep_seconds = random.random() * max_sleep
      print('Sleeping %f seconds and then retrying...' % sleep_seconds)
      time.sleep(sleep_seconds)

def uploadvideo(file, title, description, category, keywords, privacy_status):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--file', required=False, help='Video file to upload', default=file)
    parser.add_argument('--title', help='Video title', default=title)
    parser.add_argument('--description', help='Video description', default=description)
    parser.add_argument('--category', default=category,
    help='Numeric video category. ' +
      'See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list')
    parser.add_argument('--keywords', help='Video keywords, comma separated',
    default=keywords)
    parser.add_argument('--privacyStatus', choices=VALID_PRIVACY_STATUSES,
    default=privacy_status, help='Video privacy status.')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    youtube = get_authenticated_service()

    try:
        initialize_upload(youtube, args)
    except HttpError as e:
        print('An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s' % (e.resp.status, e.content))
```

### Error:

```
(venv) pi@raspberrypi:/var/www/html/GetVideo $ python3 upload_main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "upload_main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import upload_video as upload_video
  File "/var/www/html/GetVideo/upload_video.py", line 10, in <module>
    import google.oauth2.credentials
ImportError: No module named 'google'
```

Comment: Did you forget to install the Google SDK in Python3?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid How goofy i am. Yes. i forget :) However after i have installed the `google-cloud-storage` i get the error: `ImportError: No module named 'google_auth_oauthlib'`

Comment: Did you install it? `pip install --upgrade google-auth-oauthlib`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Thank you Burhan. After all, i have installed `pip install google_auth_httplib2`. and  `importgoogle-auth-httplib2` I think just httplib2 is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your program returned an [ImportError](https://www.google.com/search?q=importerror+python&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS698US698&oq=importerror+python&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5008j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)! This normally happens when you haven't downloaded a module from Python. The way to do this is run `pip install [module]` after installing [pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/). For your case, it cannot find the module [google](https://pypi.org/project/google/) so after you install pip run `pip install google`.

Hope I helped you with this solution. Have a good day!